# Вопрос связанный с БД

Tags: python, sqlite3

У меня есть игра на Python с базой данных sqlite3 и я хочу скинуть ее другу. Так вот как сделать так, чтобы бд обновлялась и у меня и у него при внесении изменений.

[image]

Можно ли сделать как-то так? И если можно, то как это сделать в программе?

Comment: посетите сайт https://dbhub.io/ там есть api, думаю этот сайт сможет решить ваш вопрос

Comment: Самый простой вариант: изменили бд, скинул файл с базой другу. Можно вручную, можно с помощью сервисов. Можно программно отслеживать изменения в  бд.   Покупаете дешевый хостинг. Размещаете там базу, и даете доступ к базе и себе и другу.

Comment: Сервис классный выше. Можно его применять.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite не является серверной базой данных. Попробуйте использовать MySql например, или, если есть возможность, разместить бд в общей для вас папке.
Так же есть возможность подключения к sqlite по SSH, но это вряд ли хорошее решение)